# Decimal Number Representation As Fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Represent the following decimal number in a fractions of integers:
>
> $38.07818181...$

$x=0.07818181...$

$10000x=781.8181...$

So $9999x=781\rightarrow x=\frac{781}{9999}$

$38*9999=379962$

So we get $\frac{380743}{9999}$ but the answer is $\frac{20943}{550}$

How did they get to this answer?

Comment: $9999x = 781.74$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to separate the integer part $38$ to get the fraction. The multiplier of $100$ I am going to multiply corresponds to two decimal shifts, which is the shortest repeating period in the decimal expansion of $x$:
$$\begin{align*}
x &= 38.078181\ldots\\
100 x &= 3807.818181\ldots\\
99x &= 3769.74\\
9900x &= 376974\\
550x &= 20943\\
x &=\frac{20943}{550}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x=38.07818181...=38.07(81)$$
$$100x=3807.(81)$$
$$10000x=380781.(81)$$
$$10000x-100x=380781.(81)-3807.(81)$$
$$9900x=376974$$
$$x=\frac{376974}{9900}=\frac{376974:18}{9900:18}=\frac{20943}{550}$$

Comment: Doesn't it create a less accurate number?

Comment: Nope. Just eliminating a common factor from the numerator and denominator.